# node cross-env can't set the class variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack

i am using `node v12.22.9`, `npm 8.5.1` and installed `cross-env: "^7.0"`

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/frontend/eyesonMeeting.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (4:10)

  2 | 
  3 |  class eyesonMeeting {
> 4 |     audio = true
    |           ^
```

how can i set the class variables without a conflict?
i have tried to replace `cross-env` by `laravel-mix` but i faced a conflict with sass.

`package.json` scripts:

```
"dev": "npm run development",
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
```

Comment: Node 12 is past end of life, stop using it (although it should support public class fields … which is what the error is about … it doesn't appear to have anything to do with cross-env).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using classes you can use the constructor to set class variables using `this`

```js
class eyesonMeeting {
  constructor() {
    this.audio = true;
  }

  // example using audio in a different function
  someFunctionSettingAudioFalse() {
    this.audio = false;
  }

  hasAudio() {
    return this.audio;
  }
}
```